# Default App Icon not appearing in iOS Simulator

Tags: xcode, interface, interface-builder, ios-simulator

I have searched quite a lot for an answer to this problem. If I have a general application, HelloWorld, and create an interface and then go to test it, then click on the Home button, not even the default grey/white icon is there like it's supposed to be. Anyone have any ideas why? I've even tried specifying a custom icon in the Info.plist file, but still nothing...

I've got the latest version of Xcode and the SDK as well. (3.25 - 4.2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it. Apparently, in order for it to put the icon there, I have to run it from within XCode, and not Interface Builder.